# Why is Java complaining about my try-with-resources block?

Tags: java, try-with-resources, autocloseable

I've got an `IncomingTrackHandlerFactory` (`ith`) which hands out instances of `IncomingTrackHandler`. These instances implements `AutoCloseable`. The `IncomingTrackHandler` deals with the database, and is short lived. Every instance is just used for a couple of queries and then discarded.

I don't get why the first block of code does not work. Why does Java tell me that it **"cannot find symbol"** for `ith`? I'm simply just declaring ith before the try block to be able to also have the `ith` variable at hand if an exception is caugth and the database transaction must be rolled back.

What am I missing?

---

[image: Non working code]

---

[image: Working code]

---

Comment: Note that it's not really *Netbeans*, but the *Java compiler* telling you that.

Comment: @kryger : yes - sorry for not being specific about that. It's not Netbeans fault, it was just my (bad) way of formulating the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ith` object is only visible inside your `try` block and is an instance of `AutoCloseable`. The instance is not visible outside, neither in catch, finally or catch block. The `ith` resource is closed automatically when an exception is thrown or the `try` block is completed. Although you can catch the exception itself, but can not operate on the `ith` object itself, only inside the `try` block.

To use the `rollback` function, you have to declare another try-catch block inside it. (Original code example omitted due source code is in image format)

```
try(Object<AutoCloseable> smth = source.get())
{
   try {
       // operate on smth
   } catch (Exception e)
   {
      smth.rollback();
   }
}
```

For more information, check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it's compulsory to declare the resource in the try-with-resources block as it's done in the second example.

From the documentation

> Because the BufferedReader instance is declared in a try-with-resource statement, it will be closed regardless of whether the try statement completes normally or abruptly (as a result of the method BufferedReader.readLine throwing an IOException).

More info here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: Do you mean that I will have to instantiate using the constructor within the try() section, and not through a factory within the try() section to hand out an instance?

Comment: You can instantiate it the way you like,but it shold be declared and instantiated inside he try section.

Comment: Alright, I was sure that I previously had done this. I assume I will have to go for a nested try-catch to be able to rollback the database transaction upon a failure inside the try section.

Comment: Hi, you may want to check this other post. It's somehow similar to what you need

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761791/transaction-rollback-on-sqlexception-using-new-try-with-resources-block