# Multiple JDBC Statements in Single Try Catch Block. is it Good Practice?

Tags: java, jdbc

I am new to Java, and my Work is all related to JDBC - about inserting and processing data. Over all its working fine.

To reduce code am using single `try{} catch()`block to write multiple `JDBC` `Statements` and `Prepared Statements`.

Example Code:

```
public void dashboardReports()
{
    try {

        String total_stock_value="select sum(price*closingstock)as tsv from purchase_table";
        Statement ps_tsv=connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet set_tsv=ps_tsv.executeQuery(total_stock_value);
        if(set_tsv.next())
        {
            total_stock.setText(set_tsv.getString("tsv"));              
        }           

        String tota_sales="select sum(INVOICE_VALUE) as iv from  PARTYWISE_ACCOUNTS_LEDGER";
        Statement st_total_sales=connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet set_total_sales=st_total_sales.executeQuery(tota_sales);
        if(set_total_sales.next())
        {
            total_sales.setText(set_total_sales.getString("iv"));
        }           

        String total_purchases="select sum(CP_INVOICEVALUE)as cpi from COMPANY_PAYMENTS";
        Statement st_tps=connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet set_tps=st_tps.executeQuery(total_purchases);
        if(set_tps.next())
        {
            total_purchases_label.setText(set_tps.getString("cpi"));
        }

        String total_collectionss="select sum(PAYMENT_REC) as payrec from PARTYWISE_ACCOUNTS_LEDGER";
        Statement ps_toco=connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet set_toco=ps_toco.executeQuery(total_collectionss);
        if(set_toco.next())
        {
            total_collections.setText(set_toco.getString("payrec"));
        }

        String total_payments="select sum(CP_PAYMENTREC) as paid from COMPANY_PAYMENTS";
        Statement ps_topa=connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet set_topa=ps_topa.executeQuery(total_payments);
        if(set_topa.next())
        {
            total_payments_label.setText(set_topa.getString("paid"));
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle except
    }
}
```

So is this Good Way to Handle or another other way?

As of now my code is working very fine, do we have any future problems with this kind of approach.

Comment: If this code works fine, you should submit it on our [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) sister site.

Comment: The biggest problem I see is that you don't close your resources, if you'd use try-with-resources that would be less of a problem, and you would automatically use smaller scoped try-blocks. BTW: Your code is inefficient: you are querying 2 tables 2 times, when you could have queried those two only once.

Answer (score 4):

This violates the [Single Responsbility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and the [Single Layer of Abstraction](http://principles-wiki.net/principles:single_level_of_abstraction) principles.

So although this code is technically valid; you should not only focus on its **correctness**, but also on its readability. And testability. And I think neither of does are "great" in the input you are showing.

Thus; coming from a clean code (quality) perspective; I would rather advise to go for something along the lines of:

```
outer method ...
  try {
    helperMethod1();
    helperMethod2();
  } catch( ...
```

with a small helper for each of the different cases you got there. And of course, you wouldn't stop there; but try to isolate *common* aspects of those helpers; and to maybe find ways to go with a single, more generic helper.

And of course: you try to avoid catching **Exception** if possible. Instead, you catch the **most specific** exception possible!

Comment: +1 I agree with what you are saying and would even like to add that as `helperMethod1` and `helperMethod2` are almost identical in functionality they could maybe be refactored to a single parameterized method

Comment: Great idea. Factored that into my answer.

Comment: @GhostCat: How to ensure clean coding in case of nested try blocks for transactions from this link - https://stackoverflow.com/a/30116055/4358787

Comment: @gaurav Clean code says: single layer of abstracting. In clean code, there is no nesting. If at all, you have method A, which calls method B in a try block, and B calls C, in another try block.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are only doing `SELECT` operations here, there is no real need for an explicit transaction, because you are not changing the state of the database, and there is nothing to rollback.  There is nothing wrong with grouping all `SELECT` statements inside a single `try` block.  However, there is a potential drawback, namely that if one `SELECT` fails, your code will exit that `try` block and all subsequent queries will not run.  If you can tolerate this, then you can leave your as is.  An analogy to this would be a series of lightbulbs connected in serial; if one breaks, then they all go out.

An alternative to what you have would be to use separate `try` blocks for each query.  Then, even if an exception were to happen in one of them, it is possible that the others could complete successfully.  The analogy here would be a series of lightbulbs in a parallel circuit.

Answer (score 2):

I think your code is ok.
You need close resultset, statement and connection in block finally.

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy with all subsequent `SELECT`s failing if one fails, then I would change the method to throw an exception

```
public void dashboardReports() throws SQLException 
{
 ....
}
```

and then catch the SQLException from the calling method.

**Note** I think it is better to throw/catch a `SQLException` rather than a `Exception`

Comment: A bit similar to what I just wrote ... feedback is welcome there.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you close your statements and resultsets:

```
try {

    String total_stock_value="select sum(price*closingstock)as tsv from purchase_table";
    try (Statement ps_tsv=connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet set_tsv=ps_tsv.executeQuery(total_stock_value)) {
        if(set_tsv.next())
        {
            total_stock.setText(set_tsv.getString("tsv"));
        }
    }

    String tota_sales="select sum(INVOICE_VALUE) as iv from  PARTYWISE_ACCOUNTS_LEDGER";
    try (Statement st_total_sales=connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet set_total_sales=st_total_sales.executeQuery(tota_sales)) {
        if(set_total_sales.next())
        {
            total_sales.setText(set_total_sales.getString("iv"));
        }
    }

    String total_purchases="select sum(CP_INVOICEVALUE)as cpi from COMPANY_PAYMENTS";
    try (Statement st_tps=connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet set_tps=st_tps.executeQuery(total_purchases)) {
        if(set_tps.next())
        {
            total_purchases_label.setText(set_tps.getString("cpi"));
        }
    }

    String total_collectionss="select sum(PAYMENT_REC) as payrec from PARTYWISE_ACCOUNTS_LEDGER";
    try (Statement ps_toco=connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet set_toco=ps_toco.executeQuery(total_collectionss)) {
        if(set_toco.next())
        {
            total_collections.setText(set_toco.getString("payrec"));
        }
    }

    String total_payments="select sum(CP_PAYMENTREC) as paid from COMPANY_PAYMENTS";
    try (Statement ps_topa=connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet set_topa=ps_topa.executeQuery(total_payments)) {
        if(set_topa.next())
        {
            total_payments_label.setText(set_topa.getString("paid"));
        }
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle except
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

1.You can have a method like , `executeQuery(Connection conn, Statement st, String sql)` to encapsulate and reduce your lines of code.

2.Don't rely on generic `Exception` , catch sql specific exception classes too

3.I don't see a `finally` block there to properly close resources unless you are doing that somewhere else. Alternatively, you can try using [try with resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax to eliminate need of `finally` block

4.See what you need to do in `catch` block - do you need to propagate exception up above the chain or fail the program right there?

5.In my opinion, a `ResultSet` and `Statement` needs to live as short as they can so try closing them as soon as you can - don't wait to close them all in single chunk. Point#1 will help in achieving this.

From technical correctness and validity perspective, there is no harm in writing code the way you did- using a single try-catch for all SQLs and eating out any exceptions ( since I see only `SELECT` sqls there) but there are clean,readable and maintainable code and on that front, your code looks poor.

Answer (score 0):

Though your code works, I strongly suggest to **refactor it for better maintenance and readability** as shown below. Also, ensure that the resources are closed properly:

```
public void dashboardReports() {
     handleTotalStocks();
     handleTotalSales();
     handleTotalPurchages();
     //Add others
}
```

**handleTotalStocks() method:**

```
private void handleTotalStocks() {
       String total_stock_value="select sum(price*closingstock)as tsv 
                     from purchase_table";

     try(Statement ps_tsv=connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet set_tsv=ps_tsv.executeQuery(total_stock_value);) {
         if(set_tsv.next()) {
            total_stock.setText(set_tsv.getString("tsv"));
         }
       }
  }
 //add other methods
```

Answer (score -1):

Better way is to create method that does common operations:

```
public String execute(String query) throws SQLException {
Statement ps_toco=connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet set_toco=ps_toco.executeQuery(query);
        return set_toco.next();
}
```

When you call this method surround it with try catch block.