# MySQL open every time a new Statement?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm working with MySQL for long time now and I know that I should only open one Connection at one time.

But now I have an other question that I think is not asked yet. If so please don't blame me, because I couldn't find an answer yet.

Every time I run a MySQL-Query or Update I open a new Statement like this:

```
Statement st = c.createStatement();
ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM ...;");
...
st = c.createStatement();
st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO ...;");
...
st = c.createStatement();
res = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM ...;");
...
```

First of all. Is it possible to create just one Statement for all the Querys and Updates? Like this:

```
Statement st = c.createStatement();
ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM ...;");
...
st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO ...;");
...
res = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM ...;");
...
```

And the other question I have is, if I have to close these Statements in the end or if Java does this automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Statement` for multiple times. It would be inefficient if you create another `Statement` object each time.

For JDBC 4.0 and earlier (Java 6 and earlier):

- A Statement is closed when the connection is closed

So if you close your connections you dont have to worry about closing statements. Closing of connections was disscussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260159/java-7-automatic-resource-management-jdbc-try-with-resources-statement)

Comment: Thanks... Because I don't close the MySQL-Connection for days

Answer (score 0):

you can create a method to do the Update/Insert action

```
public void updateQuery(String query){
...
}
```

To prevent SQL injection, try to use PreparedStatement

Comment: So I should use only one Statement for Updates... Shall I use a Statement every time I open a new Query?

Comment: you can pass the Statement to the method if you want

Comment: So I can use one only Statement for all Querys and all Updates?